# read table with spaces in one column

Tags: regex, r, import

I am attempting to extract tables from very large text files (computer logs).  Dickoa provided very helpful advice to an earlier question on this topic here: [extracting table from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464237/extracting-table-from-text-file)

I modified his suggestion to fit my specific problem and posted my code at the link above.

Unfortunately I have encountered a complication.  One column in the table contains spaces.  These spaces are generating an error when I try to run the code at the link above.  Is there a way to modify that code, or specifically the `read.table` function to recognize the second column below as a column?

Here is a dummy table in a dummy log:

```
> collect.models(, adjust = FALSE)
                                                                           model npar      AICc    DeltaAICc       weight  Deviance
5   AA(~region + state + county + city)BB(~region + state + county + city)CC(~1)   17  11111.11    0.0000000 5.621299e-01  22222.22
4                 AA(~region + state + county)BB(~region + state + county)CC(~1)   14  22222.22    0.0000000 5.621299e-01  77777.77
12                                  AA(~region + state)BB(~region + state)CC(~1)   13  33333.33    0.0000000 5.621299e-01  44444.44
12                                                  AA(~region)BB(~region)CC(~1)    6  44444.44    0.0000000 5.621299e-01  55555.55
> 
> # the three lines below count the number of errors in the code above
```

Here is the `R` code I am trying to use.  This code works if there are no spaces in the second column, the model column:

```
my.data <- readLines('c:/users/mmiller21/simple R programs/dummy.log')

top    <- '> collect.models\\(, adjust = FALSE)'
bottom <- '> # the three lines below count the number of errors in the code above'

my.data  <- my.data[grep(top, my.data):grep(bottom, my.data)]

x <- read.table(text=my.data, comment.char = ">")
```

I believe I must use the variables `top` and `bottom` to locate the table in the log because the log is huge, variable and complex.  Also, not every table contains the same number of models.

Perhaps a regex expression could be used somehow taking advantage of the `AA` and the `CC(~1)` present in every model name, but I do not know how to begin.  Thank you for any help and sorry for the follow-up question.  I should have used a more realistic example table in my initial question.  I have a large number of logs.  Otherwise I could just extract and edit the tables by hand.  The table itself is an odd object which I have only ever been able to export directly with `capture.output`, which would probably still leave me with the same problem as above.

EDIT:

All spaces seem to come right before and right after a plus sign.  Perhaps that information can be used here to fill the spaces or remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try inserting `my.data$model <- gsub(" *\\+ *", "+", my.data$model)` before `read.table`

```
my.data  <- my.data[grep(top, my.data):grep(bottom, my.data)]

my.data$model <- gsub(" *\\+ *", "+", my.data$model)

x <- read.table(text=my.data, comment.char = ">")
```

Comment: Might be good to replace situations with `" +"` and `"+ "`, separately, in case there are inconsistencies in spacing.

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta  Thank you.  That almost worked.  I had to change one line to: my.data <- gsub(" \\+ ", "+", my.data)  Then I had to set row.names = NULL in read.table.